# Добавление объекта Json в html

Tags: html, json

Ребят помогите сформировать json объект для модального окна bootstrap.Я с json не знаком особо поэтому не знаю как проще сделать. Такой вариант попросили для удобства редактирования.
Код модального окна:

```
<div id="kn9" class="modal hide fade modalros">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div class="loghead" style="width:80px; background:url('img/logo.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;"></div>
        <div class="loghead" style="width:150px; background:url('img/logo2.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;"><span class="h1modal">5,6</span></div>
        <div class="loghead" style="width:550px; background:url('img/logo3gb.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;padding-left: 30px!important;text-align:left;"><span class="h1modal" style="padding-left:0!important;">п. 9 —    Внедрение инфоцентров до уровня участка/малой группы</span></div>
        <div class="loghead" style="width:118px; background:url('img/logo4b.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;"><span class="h1modal" style="padding-left: 20px!important;">11</span></div>
        <div class="loghead" style="width:65px; background:url('img/logo5.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="line"><div class="imgop" style="background:url('img/left1.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;"></div><div class="okr"><ul><li>Повысить скорость и качество принятия управленческих решений</li><li>Снизить объем отчетности</li></ul></div></div>
        <div class="line"><div class="imgop" style="background:url('img/left2.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;"></div><div class="okr"><ul><li>Оперативные совещания руководителей до уровня начальника цеха проводятся у инфоцентра</li><li>Данные в инфоцентре регулярно обновляются</li></ul></div></div>
        <div class="line"  style="display:table;"><div class="imgop" style="background:url('img/left3.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;"></div>
        <div class="okr"  style="width:200px;"><ul><li>Руководители по направлениям</li></ul></div><div style="padding: 20px 40px 0;">
        <p style="vertical-align: middle; color: #215968; font-weight: bold;">Ключевые<br>участники</p></div>
        <div class="okr" style="width:200px;"><ul><li>До уровня руководителя малых групп</li></ul></div></div>
        <div class="line"><div class="imgop" style="background:url('img/left4.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;"><ul class="new">
<li style="z-index:4;width:150px;"><span class="grey2">1</span>Подготовить инструкции по визуализации информации</li>
<li style="z-index:3;width:130px;"><span class="grey2">2</span>Определить ответственных за качество данных</li>
<li style="z-index:2;width:170px;"><span class="grey2">3</span>Изготовить и разместить визуальные материалы </li></ul></div></div>
        <div class="line"><div class="imgop" style="background:url('img/left5.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;"></div><div class="okr"><ul><li>60 календарных дней</li></ul></div></div>
        <div class="line"><div class="imgop" style="background:url('img/left6.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;"></div><div class="okr">
        <ul><li>Единые отраслевые методические рекомендации по декомпозиции бизнес-целей, формированию Х-матриц и информационных центров предприятия в рамках подхода «Хосин Канри»</li>
        <li>Требования к результатам декомпозиции бизнес-целей и формированию Х-матриц</li></ul></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Так вот текст из модального окна должен погружаться из объекта json .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON` - простая вещь, он представляет из себя, фактически, текстовое представление объекта в `JavaScript`.

Для этих целей есть специальный объект `window.JSON`, содержащий два метода:

1. `JSON.stringify(obj)` - формирует из объекта его текстовое представление;
2. `JSON.parse(str)` - воссоздает из строки объект.

Могу предложить следующую структуру объекта:

```
var modalObj = {
    id: 'modal1', 
    header: [
        {
            selector: 'span.h1modal',
            data: '5,6',
            background: 'img/logo2.png'
        }  
    ],
    body: [
        {
            selector: 'div.okr',
            data: ['Повысить скорость и качество принятия управленческих решений', 'Снизить объем отчетности']
        }
    ],
}
```

Который как видно, состоит из трех частей:

1. `id`, содержащий идентификатор модального окна;
2. `header` и `body`, которые содержат массив данных.

Как их хранить зависит только от того, как Вы собираетесь парсить данные. В моем примере это `selector` - любой идентификатор места, в которое будут вставлены данные и сами данные `data`. Соответственно, чтобы заполнить модальное окно данными, Вы должны сначала сделать `var modalObj = JSON.parse(inputData)` и просто обойти все элементы массивов `modalObj.header` и `modalObj.body` соответствующим образом.

Comment: У меня просто 10 таких модальных окон и верстка у них отличается друг от друга а подгружать текст туда именно json поэтому я не знаю как проще представить в виде json. Мне кажется ваш вариант хорош если модальное окно одно.

Comment: К примеру подгрузка в нужное модальное окно по id

Comment: @МихаилБегунков, хорошо, можно добавить в `modalObj` еще одно свойство `id`, которое будет идентифицировать модальное окно. Я изменил свой ответ соответствующим образом.